# How to convert int value from csv to datetime in Spark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

There is such Spark SQL query:

```
spark.sql("""SELECT date, delay, origin, destination 
FROM us_delay_flights_tbl 
WHERE delay > 120 AND ORIGIN = 'SFO' AND DESTINATION = 'ORD' 
ORDER by delay DESC""").show(10)
```

View `us_delay_flights_tbl` was created from next csv:

> date,delay,distance,origin,destination
>
> 01011245,6,602,ABE,ATL
>
> 01020600,-8,369,ABE,DTW
>
> 01021245,-2,602,ABE,ATL
>
> 01020605,-4,602,ABE,ATL
>
> 01031245,-4,602,ABE,ATL
>
> 01030605,0,602,ABE,ATL

**How to convert field date to date in next format: 02-19 09:25 am from string 02190925 inside my sql query?**

Now, result looks like:

| date | delay | origin | destination |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02190925 | 1638 | SFO | ORD |
| 01031755 | 396 | SFO | ORD |

I need to get:

| date | delay | origin | destination |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02-19 09:25 am | 1638 | SFO | ORD |
| 01-03 05:55 pm | 396 | SFO | ORD |

**UPDATE**

I tried this code:

`date_format(to_date(date, 'MMddHHmm'), 'MM-dd hh:mm a')`

But got next output for string 02190925:

02-19 12:00 AM

In other words, I lost time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`to_date` transforms a string to a `date`, meaning all the "time" part (hours/minutes/seconds) is lost. You should use [`to_timestamp` function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#to_timestamp) instead of `to_date`, as follows:

```sql
date_format(to_timestamp(date, 'MMddHHmm'), 'MM-dd hh:mm a')
```